# Stackdriver logs not showing in UI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

For some reason my project is not showing logs in the page https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer and I'm prompted with the message:

> Welcome to Cloud Logging
>   View, search, analyze, and download your project's log data, all in one place. This is where you will find the logs for all your projects and Cloud Platform services.
>
> You do not have any logs in your project right now.

[image: broken logs page]

However I definitely have logs generated by a google app engine and cloud build, I can access them without a problem using the gcloud command:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gae_app" --limit 10 --format json
```

Also, I've enabled error reporting and I can see the logs there for errors, but if I click the label "View Logs" it does nothing.

There's something broken in my project but I'm not sure how to reach support in this case, also has anyone ever experienced something similar ? Is there any action that I can perform that could fix this issue ?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Are you on the correct project in the UI?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes :)

Answer (score 0):

It magically fixed itself this morning. Yesterday I've enabled stackdriver monitoring in the hope that it could fix the issue, I don't know if that is relevant.

For anyone facing the same problem, best suggestion would be to contact support. For me it fixed automatically after few days :)